# Stopping notification bar to popup during game play

Tags: xna, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, notificationcenter

**Context:**
I am working on a windows phone game using XNA 4.0 framework. During the gameplay, if the user accidentally drags the top of screen, notification center gets dragged down.

I have seen few apps where this behaviour is overridden and instead of notification center popping up, a small cue is shown at the top as shown in the screenshot below.

**Question:**
What is the API that stops notification center to come up when user accidentally drags the top of screen during gameplay?

**Screenshot of what I want to achieve:**

[image: notification center cue at the top]

Same question asked on [WP forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/509897d1-eafe-4137-b46b-e22183014fbe/stopping-notification-bar-to-popup-during-game-play?forum=wpdevelop) also but waiting for correct solution.

Answer (score 3):

To hide the notification bar, you need to do two things:

1. Set your application as full screen
2. Hide the system tray in your pages

You can set your application as full screen by changing the `FullScreen` property of your RootFrame. This can be done for instance in the App constructor, in the App.xaml.cs file:

```
public App()
{
    // Global handler for uncaught exceptions.
    UnhandledException += Application_UnhandledException;

    // Standard XAML initialization
    InitializeComponent();

    // Phone-specific initialization
    InitializePhoneApplication();

    // Hide the notification bar
    // Note: this must be done *after* InitializePhoneApplication
    RootFrame.FullScreen = true;

    // Language display initialization
    InitializeLanguage();
}
```

Then, you also have to hide the system tray on your pages, by setting the `SystemTray.IsVisible` property. This can be done either in the C# code or in the XAML:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SL8._1.MainPage"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response KooKiz. My question is in the context of XNA games. Do we have RootFrame in XNA framework also. I could not find it. :|

Comment: This solution will work, you will need to run your XNA game from silverlight. Something like this maybe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh221583.aspx#ID4EDB

Comment: The `FullScreen` property has been added in WP8.1. I seriously doubt there's a way to control the notification bar with previous versions of the runtime, since it didn't exist yet. Unfortunately,  XNA isn't supported anymore, so you would have to use a new gaming framework, such as MonoGame.