# Windwos Phone 8.1 Hidden Status Bar(System Tray)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, statusbar, system-tray

[image]

I want to add this 2 times pull status bar(top-middle part of picture) instead of just normal status bar. How can I do it? Thanks

Comment: I know it's possible for Silverlight (http://stackoverflow.com/a/23980368/869621), but surprisingly I'm unable to find how to do that on WinRT...

Comment: I was googling it for about 2 hours without any success. Is it even possible to do this in WinRT?

Comment: Also thanks KooKiz :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`StatusBar` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.statusbar.getforcurrentview.aspx) to hide the system tray, and the [`ApplicationView` API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.getforcurrentview(v=win.10).aspx) to get the double-swipe behaviour for the Action Centre. Note that this will also hide the "steering wheel" (Back / Start / Search) on all devices that have a software-drawn steering wheel *except* for FWVGA devices:

```
  var statusbar = StatusBar.GetForCurrentView();
  statusbar.HideAsync();

  var view = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView();
  view.SuppressSystemOverlays = true;
```

Comment: It hides the status bar, but does it enable the "double-swipe to show" behavior for the notification center?

Comment: This answer is correct. I've just added this to every page instead of adding it to App.xaml.cs. Thanks ...